# Why I cannot access a global variable in the same block preceding the global keyword?

Tags: python, global-variables

So in python, you can always access a global variable anywhere without using `global` keyword. Like this

```
my_global_variable = 5

def simple_func():
    print(my_global_variable)

simple_func()
```

Output:

> 5

This is all fine. Then the rule is, if I want to modify a global variable inside a method, I need to use the `global` keyword. Like this

```
my_global_variable = 5

def simple_func():
    global my_global_variable
    my_global_variable = 6
    print(my_global_variable)

simple_func()
print(my_global_variable)
```

Output:

> 6

> 6

This is all cool too. But then there's this line in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) that says "Names listed in a global statement must not be used in the same code block textually preceding that global statement". Meaning I cannot do this:

```
my_global_variable = 5

def simple_func():
    print(my_global_variable)
    global my_global_variable
    my_global_variable = 6
    print(my_global_variable)

simple_func()
print(my_global_variable)
```

If I try to run this code, I get "SyntaxError: name 'my_global_varaible' is used prior to global declaration". This is a little weird to me. Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this limitation in python?

Comment: Note that in your case you don't even need to use global at all, because lists are mutable.

Comment: `global` is only needed when a global variable is to be reassigned. It makes sense that it has to be declared before the first assignment to eliminate ambiguity. But I'm not sure why it has to be before the first reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: Without `global`, the name `my_global_variable` is a *free* variable that in this case happens to resolve in the global scope, but only because the global scope is the first enclosing scope with such a variable defined.  If `simple_func` were defined inside *another* function that had a local variable by the same name, *that* is the variable `simple_func` would use. With `global`, the name *always* refers to the global, regardless of what variables may exist in any intervening scopes.